# Alternative to pass by reference in Python to help DRY

Tags: python

I'm using Python `3.9`. Take the following:

```
class Something(QWidget):
    pass

class SomethingElse(QWidget):
    pass

class BaseWindow:
    def do_common_task(self, ptr_to_object: QWidget, new_widget: QWidget) -> None:
        # Do common stuff to new_widget.
        # Assign ptr_to_object here rather than in each method A.switch_obj_value and A.switch_another_obj_value
        ptr_to_object = new_widget

class WindowA(BaseWindow):
    ptr_to_obj: QWidget
    something_widget: Something
    something_else_widget: SomethingElse

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.ptr_to_obj = None
        self.something_widget = None
        self.something_else_widget = None

    def switch_obj_value(self) -> None:
        self.something_widget: QWidget = Something()
        self.do_common_task(self.ptr_to_obj, self.something_widget)
        # self.ptr_to_obj will be None regardless of being set in Base.do_common_task.

    def switch_another_obj_value(self) -> None:
        self.something_else_widget: QWidget = SomethingElse()
        self.do_common_task(self.ptr_to_obj, self.something_else_widget)
        # self.ptr_to_obj will be None regardless of being set in Base.do_common_task.
```

I've stripped out the context of my application.

The issue I'm having with Python is that I cannot pass the `self.ptr_to_object` as a reference into the `do_common_task` and so any operation performed on it is happening on its own instance.

What is the Python technique around this inability to pass by reference?

**Edit:**
I may have confused matters by refering to "reference". I actually meant "pointer" and I really apologise for that. My pointer isn't being updated in the child class when a pointer is passed into a Base class' method that modifies the pointer's value. It's why I thought that if I had a reference to the pointer, I could instead change the value over.

**Answer thanks to Samwise:**
I added a new class and passed an instance of that into the function instead. This allowed the pointers to be updated correctly.

Thank you all others too, very helpful.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You never defined an instance attribute named `ptr_to_obj`. What makes you think it will be `None`?

Comment: Mutable objects, typically.  Feels like `something_widget` should actually be some other object type that holds a widget pointer and implements `do_common_task`.  Hard to say without seeing a little more example though.

Comment: Oh, chepner. That's interesting. Will assigning it None do the same, as I have done that. (I'll update the question with that point)

Comment: @Samwise by "Mutable" do you mean pass through another object which holds a pointer to it and then update accordingly. If so, that's fine by me. I'll give it a try now.

Comment: Yup -- the absolute simplest thing would be to use a list of one element (since lists are mutable).  That's awkward though -- again my suspicion is that you want to use that object as a way to encapsulate `do_common_task` along with the state that it manipulates instead of just trying to simulate a C++ pointer using a list.

Comment: Since you inherit from `Base`, so `do_common_task` is a method, why not just write `self.ptr_to_object = new_widget` in that method?

Comment: I would recommend reading the [class section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) of the Python tutorial (if not the entire tutorial), as well as [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: "The issue I'm having with Python is that I cannot pass the self.ptr_to_object as a reference into the do_common_task" You can, and you do. "and so any operation performed on it is happening on its own instance" No, what is happening is that you *expect* `ptr_to_object = new_widget` to *modify the existing object* named `ptr_to_object`; but Python *never* works this way. It has nothing to do with classes, methods, Qt or anything else.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @KarlKnechtel - Perhaps i'm making a mistake. As the property on my class is passed up into the parent class, it doesn't modify the child class' property's value. So usually in C# or javascript or C++, i'd pass a ref (or a pointer) through - Just trying to figure out what the Python way is. I'm having a blast learning Python though so yahooo for Python!

Comment: There are no parent-class or child-class attributes, like in C++, only methods defined in the child or inherited from a parent. Given an instance of `A` alone, it's impossible to tell "where" an attribute was set. It might have been in a method defined by `A`, or a method defined by `Base`, or assigned directly somewhere outside of any method.

Comment: Ah. That was the nugget of info I think I needed Chepner. You legend you. I'll have a re-think and I'll improve the question if needs be. Thank you all for your help. You're so bloody kind dammit!

Comment: @Samwise - Your answer of placing the parameters as properties in a separate class has solved the issue for me. Thank you so much. And thank you all. I'm not entirely sure I understand why an instance of the class doesn't work exactly the same as another instance of a separate class, but i'll investigate properly later.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing what question you are asking, but `Base.do_common_task` will operate on an instance of `A` if that is the instance that invokes it.
There also seems to be no reason to pass anything related to `ptr_to_object` as an argument to the method; the attribute on `self` is the target, not some other variable passed as an argument.

Something like this seems to be what you are looking for,

```
class Base:
    def do_common_task(self, new_widget: QWidget) -> None:
        # Do common stuff to new_widget.
        self.ptr_to_object = new_widget

class A(Base):
    ptr_to_obj: QWidget
    something_widget: Something
    something_else_widget: SomethingElse

    def switch_obj_value(self) -> None:
        something_widget: QWidget = Something()
        self.do_common_task(something_widget)
        
    def switch_another_obj_value(self) -> None:
        something_else_widget: QWidget = SomethingElse()
        self.do_common_task(something_else_widget)
```

but a clearer description of what you want to accomplish, rather than describing how you would do something similar in a language with a completely different data model, would help.

Comment: Thank you so much by the way. The problem with this is that the Base class would now know about A, B, C classes (these are all types of windows that should have their own "pointers" to widgets on a specific window. I am playing with this idea now though. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: `Base` class knows nothing about the subclasses. It just provides a way to set an attribute named `ptr_to_object`. (Maybe that attribute doesn't even need to exist, and `do_common_task` *just* needs a `QWidget` object to operate on? There's not enough detail in your question to know.)

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, `Base` has no reason to know that the `A` class even *exists*, never mind that `A` instances have `ptr_to_object` attributes. Correspondingly, there is no reason why `do_common_task` should be given the responsibility of setting that value. Inheritance is irrelevant here (and in fact, nothing in this stripped-down example *justifies* the use of inheritance in the first place); the assignment is the responsibility of the `A` class...

```
class Base:
    def do_common_task(self, new_widget: QWidget) -> None:
        # Do common stuff to the new_widget.
        # We give the value back, so that the caller can use it.
        return new_widget
        # Notice that, in this setup, we could have equally well
        # created a new QWidget based off the input, instead of
        # modifying that widget.

class A(Base):
    ptr_to_obj: QWidget
    something_widget: Something
    something_else_widget: SomethingElse

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.ptr_to_obj = None
        self.something_widget = None
        self.something_else_widget = None

    def switch_obj_value(self) -> None:
        self.something_widget: QWidget = Something()
        self.ptr_to_obj = self.do_common_task(self.something_widget)

    def switch_another_obj_value(self) -> None:
        self.something_else_widget: QWidget = SomethingElse()
        self.ptr_to_obj = self.do_common_task(self.something_else_widget)
```

...unless, of course, `Base` instances conceptually also ought to have the `ptr_to_object`, in which case you want an approach like @chepner's (where the assumption that `self.ptr_to_object` is the thing being replaced, is hard-coded).

Please keep in mind that *the normal way to send information out of a function is to specify the `return` value, and the normal way to get information from a function call is to use that `return`ed result*. If you have a good reason to communicate information by modifying the arguments (*via* the parameters) instead, fine. But those arguments *belong to the caller*. Let the calling context handle its own data structure. Please.

Comment: Thanks Karl. The method is void because it is a method that switches one widget in a window with another widget in the same window. That functionality is coded across multiple windows (I've changed my example to WindowA and BaseWindow to give a better understanding of that). I'm reading your answer again though, it's beautiful and helpful. Thank you. I've tried creating a new class called WidgetLayoutOperationModel which has the 3 parameters as properties instead and I pass an instance of that object through to the method. This in itself has solved the pointer not updating issue. Ty @Samwise

Comment: I'm not really clear on what "switches" means in this context; but assuming that you can always just modify the passed-in Widget and that's all the main work that needs to be done, you don't need to `return` it - since the caller already knows which Widget it passed in.